# How to back out a change list by command line?

Tags: perforce

In perforce, how do you back out a specific change list through the command line?  This is easy through the GUI, but I can't find a command line command.

Answer (score 12):

The GUI is performing a series of commands. Depending on how far you want to rollback and whether or not the change includes adds/deletes/edits or just edits, the sequence of commands slightly differ.

You can refer to the [article on Perforce's KB](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Backing-Out-Submitted-Changelists) for exact details. They break it up into three different areas:

- [Backing out a recent change (edits only)](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Backing-Out-Submitted-Changelists#recent)
- [Backing out an old change (edits only)](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Backing-Out-Submitted-Changelists#old)
- [Backing out a change with adds, edits and deletes](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Backing-Out-Submitted-Changelists#tricky)

Comment: These links are dead.  You shouldn't just provide links as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of the 2016.2 release you can do:

```
p4 undo @CHANGE,CHANGE
```

to undo a changelist.

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt

```
Major new functionality in 2016.2

    #1414787 (Bug #1649) **
        A 'p4 undo' command has been added to simplify the process of
        backing out submitted changes.  See 'p4 help undo'.
```